# Basic Spinning Top Prints Fail in Same Location

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

My attempted prints on my Creative Ender3 of model:
[image: This is the spinning top totem from the movie Inception.]
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:23686

The print uses support structures (generated by Ultimaker Cura) failed in the same location twice. It is printed in PLA (1.75 mm) first print at 200 °C, second print at 196 °C.

[image: Failed print 1]
[image: Failed print 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it looks like your G-code induces an incomplete layer of support on the still standing piece, which later down leads to the print failing.

Re-slice the whole thing.

As a matter of fact, I would cut the model in its widest place and print both with the large face flat on the surface and glue the two pieces together after printing. That way I can achieve:

- no need for support material
- maximum adhesion
- no surface problems on the transition from the support to the print

Comment: Good advice to print this in 2 pieces, lots of supports are usually a pain for printing as the chances that something goes wrong increases significantly with the increasing amount of support.

Comment: Thank you Trish!!! this is exactly the kind of help and wisdom I was looking for. And it lets me know that 3d printing is not some magic press a button process (yet ;-) ) Great answer, and thank you so much!!